# How do I count the frequency of all elements in multiple arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, count

I am currently making a lottery program. I am trying to do some sort of statistics to see if there’s any bias. I’m assuming that I have to run the game multiple times and see how many times each number comes up. I am able to get the frequency of elements in a single array but I’m not too sure how I’d do that with multiple arrays.

E.g

[1,2,3,4]

[1,2,2,4] … 1 comes up 2 times, 2 comes up 3 times etc

I hope my question isn’t too confusing.

Comment: Your question is perfectly clear.  You want to do a frequency count of each item across all the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stream all the arrays, flatten them out, and then count the occurrences:

```java
int[][] allNumbers = ...;

Map<Integer, Long> counts = 
    Arrays.stream(allNumbers)
          .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
          .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: @Antoniossss That's the thing, expert like Mureinik don't use IDEs. They have all these memorized so that they can answer rightaway without any latency. Or else, other folks will beat them to the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

If you've just started learning Java, don't do Functional programming before mastering the basics.
Here's the straightforward oldschool way of doing this.

Iterate over all the arrays and store the frequency in a `HashMap`.

```
public static countFreq(int[] array, HashMap<Integer, Integer> map) {
     for (int element : array) {
         map.put(element, map.getOrDefault(element, 0) + 1);
     }
}
```

Call the utility method to count the frequency and display results.

```
var map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

countFreq(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, map);

countFreq(new int[]{1, 2, 2, 4}, map);

for (var mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(mapEntry.getKey() + " " + mapEntry.getValue());
}
```

Note: this code is for JDK/JRE 10 so `var` is used here. If it's JDK8 or lower, you have to specify the type.

Comment: What is or isn't basic is subjective.

Comment: "I am able to get the frequency of elements in a single array but I’m not too sure how I’d do that with multiple arrays."

Agreed, but from the statement above and OP's points, I assumed that she's just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

your use case is kind of confusing. Do u need to find the frequency of elements in an array of array for each array or from all arrays.

Since you r writing a lotter program, i am assuming you want to find the frequency of elements for each array in an array of array. so the output you would like to see may be

```
People1: {1 comes up 2, 2 comes up 3 etc.}
People2: ...
```